# error TS2678 Type "'String'" is not comparable to type '""' in angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement, angular5

Here's my code in angular 5:

```
gotToWallet(wallet) {

  const { countryId = '', currencyType = '' } = wallet || {};

  let walletIdentity;

  switch (currencyType) {
    case 'CRYPTO':
      walletIdentity = 'userWalletIdentity';
     break;
    case 'FIAT':
      walletIdentity = 'fiatWalletIdentity';
     break;
    case 'ERC20TOKEN':
      walletIdentity = 'xbxUserWalletIdentity';
     break;
 }

  const { currencyId = '' } = (wallet || {})[walletIdentity] || {};
  this.router.navigate([`walletMgmt/wallet-details/${currencyId}/${countryId}`]);

}
```

I am getting the following error when running `ng build` command:

```
ERROR in src/app/wallet-management/wallets/wallets.component.ts(202,12): error TS2678: Type '"CRYPTO"' is not comparable to type '""'.
src/app/wallet-management/wallets/wallets.component.ts(205,12): error TS2678: Type '"FIAT"' is not comparable to type '""'.
src/app/wallet-management/wallets/wallets.component.ts(208,12): error TS2678: Type '"ERC20TOKEN"' is not comparable to type '""'.
```

Why am i getting this error? the code seems to work fine when i run `ng serve`.
I am getting this error only when trying to make build.

Thanks, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `wallet`?

Comment: @Niek the wallet is an object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`switch (currencyType as any) {`

for some reason (maybe typescript version?), when you destruct `currencyType: ''` from wallet, it was interpreted by the compiler as type '""' instead of 'string'. so cast it as any will do the trick

Comment: I used `as string` for switching on a type that is `"something" | "else" | ""`

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by @QiaosenHuang works but it is not a good practice in terms of TypeScript as it gives up the type-safety being the main goal of TypeScript. The correct way is to pass in a typed `wallet` for example using an interface.

```typescript
interface IWallet {
  countryId: string;
  currencyType: string;
  // any other properties ...
}

function gotToWallet(wallet?: IWallet) {
  // your code from the question ...
}
```

I noted that you test for `wallet || {}` so that is the reason for using a [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) for the function argument. But your code actually doesn't do anything when `wallet` is `undefined`. So an even better solution would be to require `wallet` to be a true instance of the interface (wihtout the `?`) and move the `undefined` check outside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error and it turned out to be triggered by a cyclic import dependency with webpack.